# Stop Tasks with token used in an array of tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, token

I have this example:

```
var asyncTasks = new Task[list.Length];
for (int i = 0; i< list.Length; i++)
{
    asyncTasks[i] = tf(cts.Token, list[i]);                
}
await Task.WhenAll(asyncTasks);
//do other stuffs when all tasks completed
```

and of course i have my `async` function called `tf`:

```
private async Task tf(CancellationToken token , string list)
{
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Stopped", "Operation Aborted");
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                } 
                // do something
            }, token);
       }catch{}
       cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
}
```

EDIT: in my cancel button i declare: cts.Cancel();

This method works properly for me because it executes an array of tasks at the same time, but in my opinion I'm not able to send token for cancellation request because all `cts.Token` already assigned are valid, so if in another button i try to `cts.Cancel()` this won't work. How can i do the same but making cancellation token request valid?

Comment: Why won't it work? You've outlined exactly how CancellationTokens are supposed to work:  You pass in the token from a source and call `cts.Cancel()`.  Please [edit] your question with additional details.

Comment: modified with more details but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Is it me, or are you redundantly running a task within a task?

Comment: So what are you trying to do, start a bunch of tasks, and cancel them all at the same time with a cancellation token ?

Comment: exactly , the method works for what i'm trying to do but cancellation token it's the unique constraint

Comment: This code is wrong, why are you recreating `cts` , it wouldn't compile anyway

Comment: `if (token.IsCancellationRequested)` would only run once and wouldn't enter that condition as it wasn't cancelled upon the Task starting... You need to check that periodically

Comment: i think this is not correct.... if "token.IsCancellationRequested" is excecuted at least one time it should appear the message box content. This don't happen so the call doesn't work neither a time it's useless try to check periodically (that i already do in the entire my function but not with a timer or similar only coping and pasting the same condition after many instructions). I think that tokens are already declared like "positive" in the entire for cicle and ctf.Cancel() is useless in this scope...

Comment: @TheGeneral My code works properly, i can't fix only the cancellation token. Where should be the error?

Comment: I have a suspicion you are trying to cancel a long running method in your tasks that has no cancellation token support, is this correct? what are you calling in your tasks?

Comment: i found the error ..... what a stupid error .... i reset the token for every call with cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); at the end of task function... Thanks all for helping me

Comment: the messagebox in an async function could be one problem...messagebox has to be done in the main thread only...since its gui

Comment: @Programmer Just fyi, I rolled back your last edit; for this site, it's best to post the fix as an answer, not an edit to the question itself.  I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i reset the token for every call with `cts = new CancellationTokenSource();` at the end of task function

Function fixed:

```
private async Task tf(CancellationToken token , string list)
{
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Stopped", "Operation Aborted");
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                } 
                // do something
            }, token);
       }catch{}
}
```